# Applescript - Getting Property of an Object Not Working

Tags: applescript, messages

The dictionary for Messages states that the application has a "chat" element which has the property "updated". My goal is to get this property, and here is my code:

```
tell application "Messages"
    set _chat_ to get first chat
    set _date_ to updated of _chat_
end tell
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
Messages got an error: Can’t get updated of text chat id "iMessage;-;+<someone's phone number>".
```

This seems like a very basic thing, and yet it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This does not work because the AppleScript support in Messages.app is broken.