# Unable to read object properties with AppleScript: "Music got an error: Can’t get properties of current track."

Tags: applescript, music, big-sur

I am trying to write an AppleScript that will tell me the current playing song, but I am unable to read properties from objects in AppleScript.

Executing a function on music works fine such as

```
tell application "Music" to play
tell application "Music" to pause
```

But trying to read a property such as the current track title does not. In fact, even trying to read the properties of the current track does not work. (Tested while a song was playing)

```
tell application "Music" to get properties of current track
```

returns error `"Music got an error: Can’t get properties of current track." number -1728 from properties of current track`

Per this question, the above script should work: [AppleScript and Music](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406941/applescript-and-music/406945?noredirect=1#comment576835_406945)

I did get this to work when I was trying before when I was looking at the permissions, but then it stopped working since then so it might have been working for another reason. I'm running the script in script editor, which does have accessibility access in my security & privacy settings.

Possibly related issue: [Applescript - Getting Property of an Object Not Working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216797/applescript-getting-property-of-an-object-not-working)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error in **macOS Big Sur** 11.1, running `tell application "Music" to get properties of current track` in **Script Editor** returns the properties of the currently playing track in **Music**. Note that the currently playing track is a file located on the local disk. Where is the file located of the currently playing track that you get the error for?

Comment: I wonder if this is another Applescript perms issue. Try adding `do shell script "osascript -e 'tell application \"Music\" to activate'"` to the top of your script, then run your saved version, not from Script Editor itself. It seems to work to ask for perms. (You can trash the line once it works)

Comment: @Tetsujin I saved it outside the script editor and ran it from the terminal like `osascript music.scpt` and received the same message, and the activate works because it brought music to be the active window. 

@user3439894 I think you are on to something. This is a streaming song, not a downloaded song.

Comment: `tell application "Music" to get current track` receives error but `tell application "Music" to get player state` returns playing. So some things work. `tell application "Music" to get current stream title` returns missing value

Comment: I think it might a issue in big sur, refer to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669239

@user3439894 could you give more details?

Comment: @Fenjin_Wang, Between my first comment, which is self-explanatory, Brian's comment to me, and the info in the link of your comment, what additional details are you looking for? This is clearly an issue/bug with **AppleScript** and **Music** with a _streaming song_ as the `current track` vs. on on the local disk under **macOS Big Sur**.

Comment: Brian, everything I've ever listen to on **iTunes/Music** are songs ripped from my CD's as I do not download music or stream music. I guess it's true, the devil is in the details! :)

Comment: @user3439894 Sorry I didn't quite catch you previously, now I understand. And here is a more detailed explanation: https://dougscripts.com/itunes/2020/12/getting-properties-of-streaming-tracks/

Comment: I will test again tomorrow after upgrading to Big Sur 11.2 and see if that changes anything. At least I know that it did work at some point recently, it must have just been a downloaded song.

Comment: @Brian Actually I had tested in 11.2, problem remains...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll summarize the discussion here:

1. current track for streaming songs is broken in big sur, refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669239)
2. current track only works for local files, refer to @user3439894 and [here](https://dougscripts.com/itunes/2020/12/getting-properties-of-streaming-tracks/)

And I had verify that if you download the songs in Music and then play it, you can successfully get the info.